# make test failed when compile Node.js 4.0.0 source code in docker container

Tags: node.js, docker

There was a make test failure happened when I compiled Node.js 4.0.0 source code in Python 2.7.10 docker container.

First of all, I just run a container with Docker official Python 2.7.10 image, and container has gcc 4.9, make 4.0, python 2.7 that fulfill Node.js 4.0.0 needs.

And then operated in container (login to shell of container).

download Node.js 4.0.0 source code in /usr/src/nodejs and run below

`./configure && make && make install && make test`

The process stopped at `make test`, error message is:

```
    === release test-tick-processor ===                                            
Path: parallel/test-tick-processor
nm: '/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/9f4978cc45a4e08268de6e77e49c6e837ab58eb204846975b6db6e5474769d7b/usr/src/nodejs/out/Release/node': No such file
nm: '/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/843e2bded49837e4846422f3a82a67be3ccc46c3e636e03d8d946c57564468ba/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so': No such file
nm: '/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/843e2bded49837e4846422f3a82a67be3ccc46c3e636e03d8d946c57564468ba/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.19.so': No such file
nm: '/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/843e2bded49837e4846422f3a82a67be3ccc46c3e636e03d8d946c57564468ba/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1': No such file
nm: '/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/843e2bded49837e4846422f3a82a67be3ccc46c3e636e03d8d946c57564468ba/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.19.so': No such file
nm: '/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/843e2bded49837e4846422f3a82a67be3ccc46c3e636e03d8d946c57564468ba/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.20': No such file
nm: '/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/843e2bded49837e4846422f3a82a67be3ccc46c3e636e03d8d946c57564468ba/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.19.so': No such file
nm: '/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/843e2bded49837e4846422f3a82a67be3ccc46c3e636e03d8d946c57564468ba/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.19.so': No such file
nm: '/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/843e2bded49837e4846422f3a82a67be3ccc46c3e636e03d8d946c57564468ba/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so': No such file

assert.js:89
  throw new assert.AssertionError({
  ^
AssertionError: null == true
    at Object. (/usr/src/nodejs/test/parallel/test-tick-processor.js:34:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:434:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:452:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:475:10)
    at startup (node.js:117:18)
    at node.js:951:3
Command: out/Release/node /usr/src/nodejs/test/parallel/test-tick-processor.js
```

There is `var fs = require('fs');` at beginning of `test-tick-processor.js`. I think this command gave wrong directory that caused the problem.

How to fix this so that I can make sure Node.js 4.0.0 is correctly installed?

Answer (score 2):

As of this writing, the `test-tick-processor` test that failed for you is flaky in Node.js. There is [an open issue about it](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/2471) including this comment (11 days ago) from a core contributor:

> It seems that this test is flaky at least on all Linux platforms (likely with a much higher failure rate in armv7).

Some options to get `make test` to pass include:

- Run `make test` a second time and see if the test passes
- Disable the test by removing the file `test/parallel/test-tick-processor.js` from your source

The `require('fs')` line is not the problem. `fs` is a built-in module and there is no directory required. If that line were blowing up, you would not be getting an `AssertionError`. The stack trace indicates that the assertion is failing on line 34 of the file.

Comment: Thank you so much. I saw the ticket and it is for sure like my trouble.